# Problemas con al imprimir select con each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actualmente estoy consumiendo una `API`, todo va bien pero al momento de querer mostrar los valores en un `select` me no me imprime nada.

La Api me retorna lo siguiente:

```
{
  "producto": {
    "id": 1,
    "codigo": "PRO-0001",
    "nombre": "Disco Duro"
 },
 "precios": [
    {
      "precio_a": 200,
      "precio_b": 300,
      "precio_c": 500
    }
  ]
}
```

tengo un botón "Agregar Productos" y lo que realiza es agregar más productos a la lista haciendo petición:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function agregarLista(id){
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url : `http://localhost/proyecto/api/agregar-producto/${id}`,
    }).done(function(data){
       var row = `<tr class="item"  data-id="${ id }">`;
           row = row + `<td>${ data.producto.codigo }</td>`;
           row = row + `<td>${ data.producto.nombre }</td>`;
           row = row + `</td></tr>`;

      $("#addList").append(row);
    });
}
```

Todo va bien, pero el problema es que en la misma fila creada dinámicamente deseo agregar un select de los precios, intenté realizado de muchas maneras y una de ellas es el siguiente código:

```
row = row + `<td>
        <select class="form-control">
            ${ 
              $.each(data.precios, function(index) { 
                  `<option value="1">Hola mundo</option>`
              })
            }
         </select>
</td>`;
```

Como se puede observar no existen las opciones creadas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice peticiones `ajax` con `selects` estaticos es decir crearlos en mi HTML y ponerlos un `id` y apuntar los valores de las opciones ahí, pero en este caso el `select` es creado dinámicamente.

Este es un ejemplo cuando se crea un `select` y se manda las opciones al respectivo `id`.

```
<select id="select"></select>

$.each(data,function(key, registro) {
    $("#select").append('<option 
    value='+registro.id+'>'+registro.nombre+'</option>');
});
```

Pero lastimosamente ahora no es el caso.

Comment: Lo más adecuado es que concatenes los diferentes `option` del select en una variable y luego fuera del `each` lo asignes al DOM. Además no veo que sentido tiene imprimir un valor fijo, supongo que es solo para probar. Pero es bueno poner ejemplos basados en la realidad de lo que necesitas.

Comment: Si, pero lo que pasa es que el select lo creo dinámicamente. existe un boton (agregar mas productos) y esa es la que realiza la preticion ajax y y lo lista en el DOM.

Comment: Ya, pero en el código que muestras no veo que recojas en ninguna parte los `option` del `select` dentro del bucle, ni veo donde asignas nada al DOM. Y esa forma confusa de querer meter el `each` como dentro de una variable... ¿por qué esa práctica ?

Comment: Edité la pregunta. Thx.

Comment: Son los datos los que están vacíos o simplemente no te hace el append? Si en vez de append intentas acceder al `#select` de otra forma te deja? Tengo una idea del porque no te deja pero me gustaría asegurarme antes de desarrollar la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente debo decir que el JSON que muestras no validaría, porque tiene repetidas varias veces la clave `precio_a` en el array de precios, lo cual no es permitido en JSON.

En el siguiente código muestro una forma de resolver el problema. Consiste en lo siguiente:

- Crear una variable `theRow` a la cual ir concatenando todos los datos del JSON en forma de fila.
- Al leer el JSON se preguntará por la clave `producto`, sacando de ella las celdas `id,codigo,nombre`
- Se preguntará también por la clave `precios`, sacando de ella los tres precios mediante una nueva lectura en bucle del array de precios. El `select` se crea en una variable aparte y luego se agrega a `theRow` como una celda más.
- Finalmente agregamos `theRow` como un elemento de la tabla.

```js
var json =
  `
{
 "producto": {
  "id": 1,
  "codigo": "PRO-0001",
  "nombre": "Disco Duro"
 },
 "precios": [{
  "precio_a": 200,
  "precio_b": 300,
  "precio_c": 500
 }]
}
`;
json = JSON.parse(json);
//console.log(json);
var theRow = "<tr>";
var theSelect = "<select>";
var thePrices = "";

$.each(json, function(k, item) {
  if (k == "producto") {
    theRow += `<td>${item.id}</td>`;
    theRow += `<td>${item.codigo}</td>`;
    theRow += `<td>${item.nombre}</td>`;
  }

  if (k == "precios") {
    thePrices = item[0];
    $.each(thePrices, function(k, v) {
      theSelect += `<option value="${v}">${v}</option>`;
    });
  }
});
theSelect += `</select>`;
theRow += `<td>${theSelect}</td>`;
theRow += `</tr>`;

$("#addList").append(theRow);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="addList" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Código</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Si, me equivoqué es precio_a, precio_b, precio_c. Gracias por la respuesta, el código va más allá ya que realizo la sumas en tiempo real, analizaré el codigo. THX.

Comment: @AnthonySanchez si te refieres a la suma de los precios, eso es relativamente fácil, usando el mismo código, sería cuestión de sumar los `v`  de la variable `thePrices`...